# Understanding of $\frac{d\text{Ln}(x)}{dx}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]
I am looking into my textbook, the calculations done here are simple to follow so that is not my question, my question is is more the understanding of why they have used h in the numerator of the initial expression:

$$\frac{h}{h+x}<\text{Shaded Area}=\text{Ln}(h+x)-\text{Ln}(x)<\frac{h}{x}$$

Text book explanation:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is $\ln$ defined in your book?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I have defined updated the question about how LN is defined

Answer (score 0):

Since area of smaller retangle is $\displaystyle f(x+h)\times h=\frac h{h+x}$.

And of larger rectangle is $\displaystyle f(x)\times h=\frac hx$.

And the area under curve is greater than the area of smaller rectangle and lesser than larger rectangle, So:
$$\frac{h}{h+x}<\text{Shaded Area}<\frac{h}{x}$$